# Can't sort get_posts by post_mime_type

Tags: attachments, get-posts

I'm trying to run a query to get all attachments and I'd like to sort by the post mime type. This query isn't working. Any ideas?

```
$query_args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => null, // any parent
'orderby' => "post_mime_type"
);  $attachments = get_posts($query_args);
```

Answer (score 1):

As told by mrwweb you have to plug into Wp_Query orderby statement.

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse53783_order_by_post_mime_type' );

function wpse53783_order_by_post_mime_type( $orderby ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $order = substr( $orderby, strpos( $orderby, ' ' ) );

    $orderby = "$wpdb->posts.post_mime_type $order";

    return $orderby;

 }
```

You can apply the filter before the query then remove it with:

```
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse53783_order_by_post_mime_type' );
```

I didn't tested it but should fits your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

`get_posts()` allows the same parameters and valueas `WP_Query`. As you can see [from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), "post_mime_type" is not a valid "orderby" value. Looking at the `posts` table in the database, I can see that "post_mime_type" is saved as part of the post object but not as a custom field or anything you could get at with a vanilla `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` instance.

I think that means your only option would be a direct query of the database (which I'm terrible at, so I'll spare you a code snippet). Hopefully someone else can come along and add one ;)